# JPanel Box Layout not Responding to setMaximumSize()?

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel, dimension

I have the following code:

```
Dimension myDimension = new Dimension(400,340);

mainPanel.setPreferredSize(myDimension);
mainPanel.setMaximumSize(myDimension);
mainPanel.setMinimumSize(myDimension);
```

However when I run the app it does not listen and lets me resize it however I want, but I want it to not allow me to change the size

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the layout manager you are using.

So layout managers, like `FlowLayout` respect the preferred size.

Other layout managers, like `GridLayout`, `BorderLayout`, don't respect the preferred size.

Some layout managers, like `BoxLayout`, will respect, the maximum, minimum size.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. Sometimes you many need to nest panels with different layout managers to get the desired effect.